# In R, how does two-level parallel computing work?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, simulation, statistics-bootstrap

Suppose that I want to do bootstrap procedure 1000 times on each of 100 different simulated data set.

At top level, I can set up `foreach` backend to distribute the 100 jobs to different CPUs. Then at the lower level, by using function `boot` from R package `boot` I can also invoke parallel computing by specifying 'parallel' option in the function.

The pseudo code may look like following.

```
library(doParallel}
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
foreach(i=seq(100, 5, length.out = 100), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  sim.dat <- simualateData(i)
  boot.res <- boot(sim.dat, mean, R=1000, parallel = 'multicore', ...)
  ## then extract results and combine
  ...
}
```

I am curious to know how the parallel computing really works in this case.

1. Would the two different levels of parallel computing work at the same time? how would they affect (interact? interrupt? disable?) each other?
2. More generally, I guess there are now more and more R functions that provide parallel computing option like `boot` for intensive simulation. In that situation, is there a need to specify the lower-level parallel provided the top level? Or vice versa?
3. What are the pros and cons, if any, for this two-level parallel setup?

Thanks for any clarification.

---

**EDIT**:

I should have explained more clearly the problem. Actually after the `boot.res` is returned, more additional calculations are to be done on it to finally get summary statistics from `boot.res`. That means the whole computation is not mutually independent bootstrapping procedure. In this case, only outer parallel loop would mess up the results. So if I understand correctly here, the best way would be using nested `foreach` parallel backend, but suppress 'parallel' option from `boot`.

Anyone please correct me if I am wrong. Regards.

**END EDIT**

---

Comment: Basically it doesn't work. `boot` should work in serial or return an error (I haven't tried it). If your outer loop has (many) more iterations than you have cores available and the time per iteration doesn't differ too much between iterations it doesn't make sense to have some kind of "nested parallelization". You wouldn't have a speed advantage. If you have a situation where it makes sense, you could use the `%:%` operator from the foreach package. In particular section three of the [relevant vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: @Roland, so the better solution to this case is to use nested `foreach` parallel backend, and disable the 'parallel' option provided from whatever function itself. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: No, only parallelize the outer loop in this specific examples. You have 25 iterations of (relatively) slow code for each core. The overhead for a nested foreach loop would probably increase total computation time. Benchmark it. ;)

Comment: @Roland, Sorry I should have explained more clearly my situation. After the `boot.res` is returned, more additional calculations are to be done on it to finally get summary statistics from `boot.res'. In this case, only outer parallel loop would mess up the results as I see. Anyway, I get your point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand how that could mess up the result. But good luck.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement "the whole computation is not mutually independent bootstrapping procedure". Does the post processing performed on `boot.res` involve the results from any other iteration of the outer loop? In other words, are each of the iterations of the outer loop completely independent of each other?

Comment: @Roland, my bad here. You mean only parallelize outer 100 iterations, and then leave 1000 bootstraps under each outer loop sequential. Correct? Then"only parallelize the outer loop in this specific examples" will NOT mess up results. You are right. Sorry my mind was still on nested parallelism and I misunderstood your statement.

Comment: @SteveWeston, I misunderstood Roland 's statement "only parallelize the outer loop in this specific examples". Yes, each of the outer loop is completely independent of each other. If just parallelizing outer 100 iterations and leave inner 1000 bootstraps sequential, then that would work. My statement means that if we consider all the bootstrapping iterations (100 times 1000) as the whole computation, then each iteration is not independent of each other.